# Is it possible to play Dead Rising 2 indefinitely?

Tags: dead-rising-2

A core mechanic of the Dead Rising franchise is the ever-ticking clock towards failure of story missions. I, and many other players, find this to be threatening and limits enjoyment from the game. Near the end of Dead Rising 3 one of chapter 8's story missions will pause the countdown until the mission is completed. During this time protagonist Nick Ramos can explore with relative impunity and use the time to level up and acquire collectibles.

Is there a mission in Dead Rising 2 with a similar effect? If not, is there any other way to stop the in-game timer and explore freely without sacrificing the main questline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from starting new games and using them to supplement your walkthrough, as your playthrough's progress is preserved, you have the following options:

- You can **try using a Trainer** from [GameCopyWorld](http://gamecopyworld.click/games/pc_dead_rising_2.shtml) (not sure about the legitimacy of posting a link like that here - [Steam removes them](https://steamcommunity.com/app/45740/discussions/0/490124466460575452/)).
  I'm sure there are similar more or less reputable websites out there.
- You can try using [**WeMod**](https://www.wemod.com/): it's an app that functions as a single GUI for cheats and trainers for hundreds of games, including [Dead Rising 2](https://www.wemod.com/cheats/dead-rising-2-trainers). The website and app [seem to be safe and legit](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/wemod.com).

Comment: Too bad there isn’t any in-game method of doing this. I don't enjoy playing with mods so my hand are kinda tied. Oh well